# C# Xna interpolate edges on 2d Image like a 1d Graph

Tags: c#, xna, interpolation, procedural-generation, random-walk

I generated some caves with [random walk](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_Walk). The problem is that the output is far too small and i want to scale it up about 10-20 times. When i do so every pixel becomes visible so i need some algorithm to solve this. I thought about some sinus or cubic interpolation as it is in 1 dimension, that goes along the edges and interpolates between the centers of the pixels... So basicly the height of each pixel would be the Y axis of the graph. The image itself has only 2 "colors" wich are black and white.

The black dot is the center of each pixel and the red line the Interpolation i would like to archive:
[image: what i mean]Here is how the whole cave looks like: [image: the cave]

Is there a way to realise that? Or is it impossible? I wonder how i could solve it when the caves edge goes back on the X axis, since the graph couldnt have 2 dots for each X.

Comment: You can blur or antialias and then posterize to BW again. Basucally this is going to smooth the edges, as if you apply an exponential smoothing function.

Comment: I'll make it an answer and you can accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can blur or antialias and then posterize to BW again. Basically this is going to smooth the edges, as if you applied an exponential smoothing function.